# How to pass "- u 0" option into docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is mu docker run command :

```
docker run -it -e SERVER_URL="http://somehost:8111"  \
     --name teamcity-agent-1 \
    -u 0 \
    -v team_city_agent_config_docker:/data/teamcity_agent/conf \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  \
    -v /opt/buildagent/work:/opt/buildagent/work \
    -v /opt/buildagent/temp:/opt/buildagent/temp \
    -v /opt/buildagent/tools:/opt/buildagent/tools \
    -v /opt/buildagent/plugins:/opt/buildagent/plugins \
    -v /opt/buildagent/system:/opt/buildagent/system \
     --network apps-net \
   -d jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

I am transposing this to a docker-compose file like this :

```
 teamcityagent-01:
  environment:
   - 'SERVER_URL=http://tc-server:8111'
  container_name: teamcityagent-01
  volumes:
   - 'team_city_agent_config_docker:/data/envdata/tcagent-1/conf'
   - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
   - '/opt/buildagent/work:/opt/buildagent/work'
   - '/opt/buildagent/temp:/opt/buildagent/temp'
   - '/opt/buildagent/tools:/opt/buildagent/tools'
   - '/opt/buildagent/plugins:/opt/buildagent/pluginss'
   - '/opt/buildagent/system:/opt/buildagent/system'
  networks:
   - tools-net
  image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

The issue here is the parameter **"-u 0"** is mandadory for good functionning agent and I dont know how to transpose it into my docker compose file.

Can you help please?

Best regards

Comment: sooo `user: 0`?

Comment: Exactly: user: '0'

Answer (score 3):

Thanks KamilCuk:
It was Exactly: `user: '0'`